# ComboBox Style (Coloring)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, combobox, resourcedictionary

Does anyone know what the xaml code would be on the resource style page to change a combobox so that it has the white arrows and a blue around it.
Border - Blue
Blackground - White
Arrow - White
square around arrow - bright blue

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>


     ??????

</Style>
```

Type ComboBox into google. Go to images. Do you see how all the comboboxes have a little triangle on them this is what I am talking about when I say arrow. I want this to be White. Now look again at those images on google. You see how most of the time there is a square around the arrow on the right side of the combobox? This is what I am talking about when I say square around the arrow. I want this to be a bright blue. Now you see how most have a border that surround the whole thing. It is like a border around a button it just goes along the outside so you can see where it starts and stops. this is what I mean by border. Now the area leftover should be inside the border to the left of the arrow and the box. This is what I called the background. I want this to be white. 
I need to do this in the resource dictionary sheets. This means that every combobox I put on the screen is going to look like this automatically. In the question about I gave the outer part of the code to help people undersand what I was talking about. The question marks are where the code should go that I need. As you can see the code is in xaml. This is as descriptive as I can get. Also, I am not sure how to get the stuff from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx to work for this. I did try taking there example and it did not show an arrow at all.

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific...but if I'm understanding you correctly, you could just take a look at a [default style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx) for combobox where you'll see the "Arrow" has a `Fill` bound to "GlyphColor" as a DynamicResource that you could simply override. Your box around it though you'll have to add to the template. That is...if I'm understanding what you mean exactly. :)